# Custom serailizers/ deserializers for ObjectMapping

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson

I have add multiple custom Serializers and Deserializers to my ObjectMapper. How to check if serializers are registered?

```
 @Bean
public ObjectMapper getMyObjectMapper(List<TestSerializer> serializers, List<TestDeserializer> deserializers) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    SimpleModule customModule = new SimpleModule();

         for (TestSerailizer h: serializers) {
        customModule.addSerializer(h);
    }

    for (TestDeserializer d: deserializers) {
        customModule.addDeserializer(Object.class, d);
    }
    objectMapper.registerModule(customModule);
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

    return objectMapper;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the [`ObjectMapper#getRegisteredModuleIds`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#getRegisteredModuleIds--) that returns the set of Module typeIds that are registered in the `ObjectMapper` mapper where by default the typeId for a module is it's full class name (see `Module.getTypeId()`):

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
//it will print the modules registered    
System.out.println(mapper.getRegisteredModuleIds());
```

If you are interested to check which serializer will be used for `YourClass` class, you can invoke the [`ObjectMapper#getSerializerProviderInstance`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#getSerializerProviderInstance--) returning a `SerializerProvider` instance that may be used for accessing serializers with the `findValueSerializer` method:

```
//it will print your serializer if you have defined one for your class
//otherwise one of the jackson java classes used for serialization 
System.out.println(mapper.getSerializerProviderInstance()
                         .findValueSerializer(YourClass.class));
```